# Removing duplicates with Hash Set for a Linked List, I can't understand the work flow of code

Tags: java, hash, linked-list, duplicates, singly-linked-list

The problem is to remove duplicates from an unsorted Linked List. Using a hash set keeps track of the values already in the set.

I do not understand what the if, else block is doing.
Especially the code, prev = current.

Does that overwrite the prev from before?

I drew out multiple diagrams on a whiteboard and can't understand the flow of this code

```
public void removeDuplicateFromUnsortedList() {
    HashSet<Integer> hs = new HashSet<Integer>();

    Node current = head;
    Node prev = null;

    while(current != null) {

        int current_data = current.data;

        if(hs.contains(current_data)) {
            prev.next = current.next;
        }
        else {
            hs.add(current_data);
            prev = current;
        }

        current = current.next;

    }
}
```

This is the desired result, which works.

Printing out:
1 --> 1 --> 4 --> 2 --> 4 --> 2 --> 2 --> null

Printing out:
1 --> 4 --> 2 --> null

Comment: For the first node, prev and current both will point it at the end of while loop, from second iteration - since hashSet contains the data, prev.next will hold current.next, where current is the second element, so the second '1' will be removed from the list. You probably are not used to the assignment statement of linked List, get a book and see some graphical examples.

Comment: Hi @ManojBanik, I am glad that you replied. After spending an unreasonable amount of time, solving this code, I finally understand it. And with your explanation just proved it. Essentially, prev and current, since "prev = current" are working on the SAME linked list. I thought it was totally separate! Now with that in mind, when prev.next = current.next, it skips the node that is duplicated. Is that correct, please give feedback :)